# Confluence configuration Spring Application context has not been set

Tags: java, confluence

I tried to install confluence on my own ubuntu server, but always failed. The error is:

```
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Application context has not been set
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:149)

caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Application context has not been set
at com.atlassian.spring.container.SpringContainerContext.getComponent(SpringContainerContext.java:48)
```

I saw some solutions in the jira confluence forum saying try to fix the permission of installed directory and home directory. I tried but failed again. How can I fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was corrupted **confluence.cfg.xml** file (contains DB connection stings and other settings). The file size was 0 bytes.

I would suggest to use a VM to create a new installation and borrow confluence.cfg.xml from that installation.

It's embarrassing that this behavior has been allowed to exist for nearly 7 years in a commercial product. This is a basic stuff...

I wish that was on instructions somewhere:
[Make single backup copy of confluence.cfg.xml immediately before any writes to it by the application. Application should be able to restore from backed up copy if it gets corrupted.](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-8898)

Comment: 10 years. It's still a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-does-not-start-due-to-spring-application-context-has-not-been-set-218278311.html) lists the following causes of this problem:

1. The user running Confluence does not have write permissions to the home folder defined in `<install>/confluence/WEB-INF/classes/confluence-init.properties` or the install directory.
2. You are running Confluence as the `root` user or if you have an application firewall enabled (SeLinux or AppArmor).
3. The database driver is not located in the `<install>/confluence/WEB-INF/lib` folder or you are using a database version that is incompatible with the bundled driver.
4. The hostname of the server can not be resolved.

In my case I was running it as root user inside docker container.